# Bootstrap placing forms next to eachother

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position

Trying to put three of my first forms in the center of the container and put the last two forms next to the first three. Trying to use float, but that didn't work.

Any help is much appricieted:

bootply: http://www.bootply.com/125841

How I want it to look:

[image]

Comment: could you be more clear how you wanna put your 5 label, 5 textfield and button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
you put everything inside a div with class="everything".

```
.everything {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

then you put the first three group of textfields in a class called .blocks and the other three groups of textfields and button in another div called .blocks too.

```
.blocks {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
```

here you are fella:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                  <div class="block">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password1</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="block">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password2</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password3</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                        <button id="onlyButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.jumbotron {


  /*  display: inline-block; */
    margin-bottom: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 623px;
}

.block {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;

}
.container {

    min-height: 530px;
     /* set border styling */
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;  
    width: 600px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    overflow:auto;


    /* set border roundness */
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;



    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
  /* display: inline-block; */
    background-color: white;


}

.form-horizontal {

padding-right: 150px;

}

.form-control {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#onlyButton {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Could you please show it with my bootply? Thanks, much appricieted.

Comment: Thank you very much sir prelite, I am just wondering about one thing. How do I make it look mobile friendly? Because I was wondering if you look it with a mobile screen the two tables at right would go under the others in left? Right now its overlayering the left ones.

Comment: Copy this at the very end of your css file @media (max-device-width: 480px)
and (orientation: portrait) {.block {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

} if my answer is good please check it as good one...very glad to help...